# P0101 and P2113 codes removal Kia Rio 2011

Tags: throttle, can-bus, dtc

I have a KIA Rio Diesel car from 2011. With a diagnostic tool I have read the `P0101` and `P2113` DTC's:

[image]

I had an old and problematic throttle body. I have replaced it with a completely new one and took a ride- everything works. My problem now is that I cannot remove the DTC's. They are stored, not pending- when removing them manually using ODB2 tool, they automatically reappear. How to remove them permanently (at least for now, until another event causing the event occurs, if any). I would appreciate all help.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! SInce you are deleting them and they are coming back, how do you know you haven't resolved the issue in the first place? [P0101](https://www.samarins.com/diagnose/p0101.html) has to do with the MAF and [P2113](https://www.obd-codes.com/p2113) with the TPS or pedal position sensor ... only the P2113 is remotely related to the throttle body (not directly related). I'd ensure you don't have other issues still pending.

Comment: Hi, thank you for answer. You are right, there might still be some problems pending. But shouldnt I reset the errors and check either they will come back up again as a test?

Comment: If you are deleting them and they come right back, means the computer is seeing the error right from key turn and reporting them.

Comment: I see then. What would you suggest for checking next? Should I try to clean the MAFS or replace it for P0101? As for P2113, I really hoped that replacing the throttle body with its electronics circuit would work. I would appreciate your further help.

Comment: Clean the MAF. Good start. Might be the connection, so check that as well. Did you adjust the TPS when you installed the new TB? Is it a new TPS? Did you check the wiring for the TPS and for the MAF?

Comment: I did not adjust anything when installing TB, did not know I need to. How can the TPS be adjusted? Its a brand new TB. I have checked the connectors for TB and MAFS, seemed clean. I dont have the MAFS cleaner now, so I need to buy one. Or maybe air under high pressure would be enough?

Comment: DO NOT use pressurized air to clean the MAF, you'll damage the sensor. Electronic spray cleaner would work just fine. I don't have the procedure for adjusting the TPS it is something which absolutely needs to be done.

Comment: But I am not sure why do I need to touch the TPS at all after reinstalling the TB? It is a completelly different part, not connected together mechanically. Could you explain?

Comment: Ok, just to make things clear- my throttle body is not connected mechanically with my pedal at any point. The signal driving the throttle is electrical- comes from the on board electronic regulator. Doesnt that mean I can only calibrate it using odb software?